# Sencha ExtJS 6 global CSS not found

Tags: css, extjs, http-status-code-404, extjs6, file-not-found

I am trying to run base Sencha application packaged as WAR on web server. The application does load but there is a 404 error in loading the CSS files. However I can view them in my target folder. Please find the screenshots below. Any Idea?

[image: Error on application loading]

[image: Files are available in target directory]

Comment: Yes This is a weird problem I am also facing from past few weeks. The solution which I am using is : 1. Refresh your app `sencha app refresh` and then 2. build your app `sencha app build`. Your css file in build folder is missing because of refreshing app or may some other reason. so do that. It will work.

Comment: @UDID From the screenshot we can see that the CSS file exists.

Comment: I am building sencha app from maven, so can't do that

Comment: Meena, which web server do you use? Which operating system, and which file system? I strongly believe that the problem lies with too long/deep a path.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary : As suggested by UDID why dont you do *sencha app build*,because it will again compile and build your app.Can u please try it and reply.

Comment: @Alexander yes agree but some time because of adding new js or css files we need to refresh and make new build for come out from this error. though files are present.

Comment: I have tried rebuilding it but still got the problem. Also as I mentioned earlier I build my sencha app using maven build

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary I am not sure weather it will work or not but in trial and hit you try this. -- Delete build folder and then generate build. "Sencha app build -c".

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary Is it a classic app or modern ?

Comment: It's classic app

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary Then no prob. Take a backup of build folder and regenerate build.